# How to use Linux computer's mouse on a remote Windows computer?

Tags: windows, linux, mouse, tablet

I've got a Linux tablet, and would like to use it to control the mouse on my remote Windows computer. Is there any currently existing software that would allow me to do this?

If it matters, the tablet is x86 and is running Xubuntu. I've looked at Synergy, but it seems that will not work where the mouse will never go off the screen.

Comment: Tried Teamviewer? I've controlled my desktop mouse using Teamviewer for Android mobile. Should work for Xubuntu too.

Comment: Are you using the old Synergy or the new [synergy-plus](http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/) ?

Comment: According to the site, synergy and synergy+ have combined efforts. I've been using the latest 1.4.4 version.

Comment: what about http://www.splashtop.com (by using android on the tablet)

Comment: The serial Wacom tablet doesn't work with Android-x86.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure synergy to have incoming but not outgoing links to the screen, though you would likely have to manually configure synergy to do that - see the part of the [config file docs on links](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/configuration.html), that says

> It's possible to configure a screen with no outgoing links; the
>   cursor will get stuck on that screen unless you have a hot key
>   configured to switch off of that screen

Alternately, [scroll lock will keep the mouse from moving off the screen](http://synergy-foss.org/tracker/projects/synergy/wiki/UserFAQ#Q-How-do-I-lock-the-mouse-on-one-screen)

Comment: OK, I've got Synergy semi-working, However, when I put the mouse on the second monitor, it goes to "relative" mode, which obviously isn't going to work well. Is it possible to set it to "absolute" mode?

Comment: you have to set that on the server - according to the config docs linked above, its the stanza that says relativeMouseMoves

Comment: relativeMouseMoves only changes how the moves are physically done on the client screen, not how they are interpreted from the server. It's still switching to interpreting it as relative positioning as soon as it goes to the client screen.

Comment: It's actually not hard to configure this... I know, because I've done it by accident :)

Comment: Is there something other than relativeMouseMoves that needs to be set? The Synergy manual doesn't seem to say anything else about it...